# Sublime editor auto add extra empty lines

Tags: sublimetext3

When I open my code using sublime just now, for some unknown reason there are a lot extra spaces added. I never face this issue before. After re-install sublime it became like this.

[image]

Some files are just fine

[image]

Comment: Were both the files created in Sublime, or did they come from other sources?

Comment: @MattDMo both created from sublime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those who is facing the same issue, this is not the editor problem but by the FTP. In my case, I was using FileZilla and the setting from this FTP was the one that changing the structure of the code when doing the file transfer.

Change the setting:

From FileZilla > Transfer > Transfer type > choose `Binary`.